# JCE in AdoptOpenJDK 11

Tags: jce, adoptopenjdk

Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) can be found [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-all-download-5170447.html), but that page says

> Current versions of the JDK do not require these policy files. They are provided here for use with older version of the JDK.
>
> JDK 9 and later ship with, and use by default, the unlimited policy files.

Does this apply to [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) 11 as well? Or is this restricted to Oracle's JDKs? How do I know they are available?

Answer (score 7):

According to [this guide](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/05/migrating-from-oracle-jdk-to-openjdk-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-what-you-need-to-know/):

> I’ve been asked whether Java’s Cryptography/Security extension (JCE) is supported in OpenJDK. The answer is [yes it is](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1363643?extIdCarryOver=true&sc_cid=701f2000001OH6pAAG). As a note, in [OpenJDK as of 8b161](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189383), unlimited cryptography policy is enabled by default (previously you had to [download the unlimited strength files manually from Oracle](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1524443)).

Comment: The first link is restricted, but the bug entry sounds promising. But regarding the last question ("how do I now they are available"): What can I do to verify that locally with my installation?